# Работа с нативным кодом из .Net Core

Tags: c++, dll, .net-core, native

У Microsoft есть статья, посвященная работе с нативным кодов в .Net Core на различных платформах. Да, они приводят некоторые примеры, но О МНОГОМ не договаривают. Например, тут они вызывают функцию из WinAPI, чтобы вывести сообщение на экран
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А вот если dll-ка скомпилирована 32 битым компилятором, например стандартным из комплекта поставки Code::Blocks на Windows с MinGW32, то программа улетает с исключением **BadImageFormatException**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хотелось бы видеть ЖИВОЙ пример работы с нативным кодом на примере доступа к всплывающим уведомлениям на Ubuntu и Windows 10

Comment: Судя по вашему собственному ответу, исключение вылетело, так как вы пытались загрузить 32-битную dll в 64-битный процесс. Атрибут `DllImport` и иже с ним появился далеко не вчера и подробно описан в документации. Никакого "О МНОГОМ не договаривают" нет.

Comment: @VIT Для меня есть разница в вызове нативного кода и участка динамически подключаемой библиотеки, так как этот нативный код ещё нужно скомпилировать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ссылку на скачивание ВСЕГО примера я оставил в самом низу ответа на вопрос

**Linux**

Тут всё просто, на 64 битной системе gcc по умолчанию будет компилировать 64 битные бинарники. Соответственно, задача сводится к написанию простейшей сишной функции, код снизу

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libnotify/notify.h>

int notify(const char *title, const char *description,int timeout)
{
  notify_init("dcnn");
  NotifyNotification* n = notify_notification_new (title, description, 0);
  notify_notification_set_timeout(n, timeout);

  if (!notify_notification_show(n, 0)) 
  {
    printf("Notification fallen");
    return -1;
  }

  printf("Notificated");
  //notify_uninit (void);
  return 1;
}
```

Ничего сложного. Не вглядывайтесь в содержимое, это просто функция, которая может вернуть значение. main() кстати не нужен, так как далее мы вынесем её в .so, который сам по себе не будет запускаться. Компилируем через gcc со следующими параметрами:

```
gcc -Wall -shared -o native.so -fPIC native.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 libnotify` -lnotify
```

Тут важно компилировать одной командой. Да, есть возможность сначала получить объектные модули .o, но компилятор при этом обязательно что нибудь забудет добавить... Рекомендую так же не отходя от кассы попытаться сделать динамичный импорт библиотеки из другой сишной программы, в репозитории в папке ubuntu лежит файл testing.c c её реализацией. Но если можете написать сразу правильно, то можно и пропустить

После сборки получаем файл **native.so**. Его нужно закинуть в папку со сборкой для .Net Core. По умолчанию у меня сборка появилась в директории

```
DotnetCoreNativeNotifications/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/
```

Далее вызывается это дело просто. Всё как в документации MS

```
public class UbuntuNotify : AbstractNotify
{
    public UbuntuNotify(){}

    [DllImport("native.so")]
    private static extern int notify([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string title,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string description, int timeout);

    public override void Notify(string title, string desc, int timeout)
    {
        UbuntuNotify.notify(title,desc,timeout);
    }
}
```

В Program.cs я проверяю if-ом платформу, создаю экземпляр этого класса и вызываю метод Notify

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Windows**

Для начала выбираем правильное ПО для прикладного программирования. Не рекомендую пытаться написать dll в Visual Studio. На мой взгляд, она заточена ИМЕННО под C# и процесс написания динамически подключаемой библиотеки в ней затянется на долгое время, так как **тупо нет шаблона проекта, собирающего dll**

Берем Code::Blocks, http://www.codeblocks.org/

Далее ставим на него **64 битный компилятор**. Это важно, без него .Net Core  посчитает dll некоректной

Статья как поставить такой тут, https://medium.com/@yzhong.cs/code-blocks-compile-64-bit-under-windows-with-mingw-w64-79101f5bbc02

Создаем проект dll, язык C++
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не забудьте выбрать ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ компилятор
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее он сгенерирует достаточно читаемый код. Посмотреть код dll который выводит уведомления на Windows можно тут https://github.com/tripolskypetr/DotnetCoreNativeNotifications/blob/master/windows/native/main.cpp

После того, как закончили написание dll, так же кидаем его в папку со сборкой .Net Core, для обращения я реализовал следующий класс

```
public class WindowsNotify : AbstractNotify
{
    public WindowsNotify(){}

    [DllImport("native.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private extern static void NotifyFunc([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string title, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string desc);

    public override void Notify(string title, string desc, int timeout)
    {
        WindowsNotify.NotifyFunc(title,desc);
    }
}
```

В итоге у нас получился проект .Net Core, который и на Ubuntu и на Windows 10 вывел нам уведомление. Чудеса
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ВАЖНО:** На разных версиях десятки может не работать, так как используется WinAPI и оно тоже меняется... Мой компьютер работает на версии 1703, она достаточно старая. Рекомендую попробовать тот же пример, но в dll на Windows вызывать функцию MessageBoxA как в шаблоне dll среды Code::Blocks, надеюсь мелкомягкие до неё не доберуться. Про linux я спокоен...

```
void DLL_EXPORT SomeFunction(const LPCSTR sometext)
{
    MessageBoxA(0, sometext, "DLL Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}
```

Посмотреть полный код данного примера можно тут, https://github.com/tripolskypetr/DotnetCoreNativeNotifications

Comment: "О МНОГОМ не договаривают" - и какие недоговоренные моменты вы тут раскрыли? "тупо нет шаблона проекта, собирающего dll" да ладно?

Comment: @VTT обязательный 64 битный компилятор на Windows для dll, например...

Comment: Ничего подобного. VS из коробки позволяет собирать 32- и 64- битные dll.

Comment: @VTT MSVC умеет собирать, безусловно. Но мне показалось не очевидным требование к разрядности конечной dll для работы из .Net Core.

Comment: Как это "не очевидно"? Если собираете 32-битное приложение .Net Core, то и библиотеки оно сможет грузить только 32-битные, если собираете 64-битное приложение .Net Core, то и библиотеки оно сможет грузить только 64-битные. Разве когда-то было по-другому?

Comment: @VTT программы .Net Core это не бинарники, а набор кодов IL для CLR - виртуальной машины. Как виртуальная машина будет обрабатывать нативный код - вещь не очевидная, лично я не видел реализацию. А на сайте МС не пишут разрядность скачиваемого пакета .Net Core для разработки https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/

Comment: Программы .Net Core это все те же 32-битные или 64-битные бинарники, выполняющиеся внутри 32-битного или 64-битного процесса. В каком виде в них содержится байт-код, и как он интерпретируется - не столь важно. Потенциально они могут быть и нейтральными, но тут главное разрядность исполняющего процесса. Разрядность скачиваемых пакетов [подробно расписана](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows).

Comment: @VTT Н-да, а я думал мс не сделали 86 версию .Net Core